# How to programmatically detect if the word(2003) document is corrupted?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programatically tell if a word document is corrupt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924128/how-to-programatically-tell-if-a-word-document-is-corrupt)

I want to check if word(.doc binary format) document is corrupted using c#. 
I'am generate PDF and html from existing doc files using Interop.Word and want to detect and isolate corrupted doc files for manually processing.
Interop.Word do not generate any exception or event if file is corrupted it just show a dialog box for choosing right encoding. I suppress all dialogs using flag "DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone" because where's stop process execution.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try to open file and in case there is exception thrown, then assume the file is currupt. I don't think there is a library out there for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the Word document as described [here](http://zirmandli.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/read-word-doc-using-c/). You should get an exception if the document is corrupted. (also take a look at the question posted in the comment below your question)

Comment: A word document may be reported as corrupt if the filesystem underneath the word document is suffering from problems.  Or if there are hardware failures in the machine reading it.  Or if the Word Program reading the file is corrupt.  Just because you get an exception reading the file does not prove the bytes in the file are the culprit.  You could try to open the file in OpenOffice as well to isolate the problem.

Comment: Yes you're right. These cases should be very rare so I was implicitly assuming that anything else worked.